# adding clustering to Fviz_PCA_biplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I have built a fviz_pca_biplot using this code

```
ph <- "Physiological"
ag <- "Morphological"
trait <- factor(c(ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ph,ag,ag,ag,ag))

fviz_pca_biplot(pc1, geom.ind = c("text","point"), labelsize = 5,
                pointshape = 22,pointsize = 3,font.family = "serif",
                fill.ind = ct$Species,
                col.ind = "black",
                col.var = trait, 
                repel = T, parse = T,
                legend.title = list(fill = "Species", color = "Traits"))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-4.5, 4.25), ylim = c(-3,3.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1.25,2.5,3.5),
                     labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-4.75,-3,-1.5,0,1.5,3,4.5))+
  fill_palette(c("#E5871A","#1AE522", "#1A78E5","#E51ADD"))+ 
  color_palette(c("darkgreen", "#1A0DB6"))+
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x =element_text(colour="black", size = 9, family = "serif", face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y =element_text(colour="black", size = 9, family = "serif", face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold",family = "serif",colour = "black",size = 9),
        plot.title =element_text(vjust = -9,hjust=0.01,face = "bold",family = "sans", size = 10),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "right", #legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9,face="bold.italic",family = "serif"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "a.", x= "PC1 (32.49%)", y= "PC2 (21.51%)")
```

Then I have calculated the clusters using this code

```
HCPC(pc1, method = "ward", metric= "euclidean", graph=T, order = T)
```

Now I want to show the obtained clusters in the same graph which I made earlier through fviz_pca_biplot
and the final graph should looklike this
[image]
I darw the clusters manually but I dont know how to do it with ggplot.
My idea is, if i can join the individual of same clusters by drawing a line just like convex type.

Answer (score 0):

With  `library(ggforce)`
`geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = df$Clust,),alpha = 0.3)`
this code line helps me make cluster ellipse on the `fviz_pca_biplot`
you can replace `ellipse` with `hull`, `circle` also
for example
[image]